# Need help building an odd Sequelize query

Tags: mysql, database, orm, sequelize.js, relational-database

Some context:

I have two tables: `challenges` and `participants`.

`challenges` table columns: `id`, `userId`, and `name`.

`participants` table columns: `id`, `userId`, and `challengeId`

The `userId` column on the `challenge` table indicates ownership of a challenge.

The `participants` table is simply an association table to keep track of users who have joined challenges.

`challenges.hasMany(participants)`

`participants.belongsTo(challenges)`

The owner of a challenge may or may not be a participant.

---

My question:

How can I construct a single Sequelize query to find all owned OR joined challenges for a specific user?

Example Data:

```
challenges
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | userId |    name     |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 |   2001 | Challenge 1 |
|  2 |   2002 | Challenge 2 |
+----+--------+-------------+

participants
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | userId | challengeId |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 |   2001 |           1 |
|  2 |   2002 |           1 |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

Desired result of finding all owned OR joined challenges of user `2002`:

```
challenges: [
  {
    id: 1,
    userId: 2001,
    name: "Challenge 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    userId: 2002,
    name: "Challenge 2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Just so I understand what you're looking for, you want a list of any challenge the user is the owner of OR any they have participated in?  Not necessarily a list of their challenges where they are also a participant?

Comment: Yes, correct. Apologies if that was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT challenges.* 
FROM      challenges 
LEFT JOIN participants 
       ON challenges.id = participants.challengeId 
WHERE challenges.userId   = 2002 
   OR participants.userId = 2002;
```

Comment: This query accomplishes the goal. Thank you! Now I just need to figure out how to convert this into a Sequelize query...

Comment: While I'm not familiar with Sequelize, their docs say you can run raw sql commands: Sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM THING')